# can't find main(String[]) method in class

Tags: java

I am getting the following error :

> can't find main(String[]) method in class

```java
import java.util.*;

class Coor {
    int x, y, w;
    Coor(int x, int y, int w) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.w = w;
    }
}

class Xc {
    int c = 0;
    int d = 10;
    Xc(int c, int d) {
        this.c = c;
        this.d = d;
    }

}

public class TcsDigital {
    int n = 4;
    boolean visited = false;
    boolean[][] varray = new boolean[n][n];
    //int array[][]=new int[n][n];
    int array[][] = {
        {
            1,
            8,
            21,
            7
        },
        {
            19,
            17,
            10,
            20
        },
        {
            2,
            18,
            23,
            22
        },
        {
            14,
            25,
            4,
            13
        }
    };


    public boolean check(int r, int c) {
        if (r >= 0 && r < n && c >= 0 && c < n && varray[r][c] == false)
            return true;
        return false;
    }

    public void fun(int[][] a, int r, int c, int w) {
        if (r == n - 1 && c == n - 1) {
            System.out.println("Reached");
            return;
        }

        varray[r][c] = true;

        if (check(r + 1, c) == true) {

        }
        if (check(r - 1, c) == true) {

        }
        if (check(r, c + 1) == true) {

        }
        if (check(r, c - 1) == true) {

        }
        varray[r][c] = false;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TcsDigital t = new TcsDigital();
        t.fun(t.array, 0, 0, t.array[0][0]);
        //Stack <Coor>stack=new Stack<Coor>();
        Stack < Xc > stacks = new Stack < Xc > ();

    }
}
```

An error occurs can't find main(String[]) method in class 
says by java version 12.x
what reason it says like that, but it compiles well in online compilers like `onlinegdb.com`, GeekforGeek- IDE, but not compile offline in java, I programmed with notepad++ and run directly at the command window

> can't find main(String[]) method in class:Coor

Comment: The `main` method exists in `TcsDigital` but seems you are running `Coor` class. What is the name of the `.java` file you saved? Do you have an individual `.java` file for each class?

Comment: IIRC the file-name needs to reflect the "main class" in the source file. So if your "main class" is named `TcsDigital` then the source file needs to be named `TcsDigital.java`.

Comment: I solved ,the real reson behind this is i should put Tcsdigital class at top of my program, eventhough my file name is Tcsdigital.java.

Comment: Indeed, I had a similar issue and your suggestion worked. Thanks for sharing ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java is looking for the `main` method in the `classname.java` file you want to compile. The name of the file has to correspond with the class found in it.

My suggestion is, that your file is not named `TcsDigital.java`, therefore java is taking the first java class it finds, which is `Coor`. Since `Coor` does not contain a `main` method an error occurs. 
You should try renaming your file to `TcsDigital.java`.

I recommend to write every java class in a sepreate file and to import them as needed. An additional *Main* class containing only the `main` method is an option, too.

Comment: I solved ,the real reson behind this is i should put Tcsdigital class at top of my program, eventhough my file name is Tcsdigital.java.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the reason, but if we order out public class higher in the order it is executing without giving error.

Answer (score 0):

compile the java program and run java class file by using (java classname) instead of (java classname.java).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).